# Двойной указатель (**)

Tags: c, массивы, указатели

Всем привет! У меня такая история. У меня есть двойной указатель на двумерный массив строк. Я написал функцию, которая должна бы выписывать нужное имя(в данном случае "misa"), но вместо этого она принтует мне 0. Сложно разобраться с указателями (да и еще двойными, да и еще на двумерный массив!). Был бы очень рад, если кто-нибудь помог бы мне в этом деле. Наперед благодарен!

Код

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_name(char** array, const int num) {
    printf("%d\n", *array[num]);
}

int main()
{
    char* names[3][4];

    names[0][0] = "kola";
    names[1][0] = "vasa";
    names[2][0] = "misa";

    print_name(*names, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

upd: Если я вывожу строку "%s", то мне показывает такое сообщение

```
format ' s' expects argument of type 'char *' but argument 2 has type 'int ' -wformat=
```

и выводит `(null)`

Comment: Вы хотите выписывать строку, а используете спецификатор `%d`

Comment: @вася я обновил, посмотрите пожалуйста

Comment: Вообще-то у вас - так, на всякий случай - двумерный массив указателей на строки, которые хранятся где-то за пределами этого массива. Т.е. `names[0][1]` у вас - неинициализированный указатель, например. Это вы понимаете? (Чтоб понимать, отдаете ли вы отчет в том, что делаете). Просто мне кажется, что *хотите* вы *на самом деле* `char names[3][5]; strcpy(names[0],"kola"); .....`

Comment: @Harry то есть мне надо, перед тем как использовать этот массив, проинициализировать его с помощью malloc/calloc?

Comment: Это не обязательно, если вы делаете именно то, что хотите. Например, если у вас ваш двумерный массив действительно будет содержать в пределе 3*4=12 строк. Просто аккуратно работайте и все. Но если вы рассчитывали на 3 строки по 4 буквы - то тогда это делается не так. Сколько строк может поместиться в ваш массив? :)

Comment: @Harry я 100% знаю что там будет именно 3*4, просто не знаю как мне вывести именно заданное конкретное слов..

Comment: Тогда вам нужны два числа - строка и столбец, нет? Или вы их нумеруете от 0 до 11? так тоже можно...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выделяем память под двумерные массивы правильно. Выделим одним блоком память (`malloc`) и под указатели на указатели (`N*sizeof(char*)`) и под указатели на символы (`M*N*sizeof(char)`). Очистка памяти,выделенной подобным способом, производится с помощью одной функции `free`. (+можно передавать в параметры к функции лишь указатели - функция `print_name_1`). [Пример](https://ideone.com/a8uT7h):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define N 3 //кол-во строк
#define M 5 //кол-во символов в строке (4 символа + '\0' для разделения строк в памяти

void print_name(char** array, const int num) {
    printf("%s\n", array[num]);
}

//или так
void print_name_1(char* array, const int num) {
    array += M*num;
    printf("%s\n", array);
}

int main()
{
    //char* names[3][4];
    //выделяем память правильно!
    char **names = (char**) malloc(N*sizeof(char*) + M*N*sizeof(char));
    names[0] = (char*) (names + N); //указатель на первый символ
    for(size_t i=1; i<N; i++)
        names[i] = names[0] + M*i;  //смещаем указатель под начало строк
    
    //используем функцию strcpy из <string.h>
    strcpy(names[0],"kola");
    strcpy(names[1],"vasa");
    strcpy(names[2],"misa");
    
    
    print_name(names, 2);
    
    print_name_1(names[0], 0);
    
    free(names);    //освобождаем память одной функцией free
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: спасибо Вам большое, это то что я хотел!)))
Только если бы Вы могли немного детальнее объяснить (или скинуть статью) о том, как (и зачем) Вы сместили указатели, я бы был ооочень рад)))

Comment: @ancores, в своей функции print_name_1 я смещаю указатели на размер блока памяти, в котором содержится строка ( array += M*num ). Я выделил память под указатели на указатели и указатели на данные вызовом 1 функции malloc. 
Переводим указатель names[0] на начало области данных (т.е. мы записываемых для N указателей область памяти по M единиц памяти) и указывает остальным N указателями на начало их области памяти, расположенной в одном блоке, что позволяет сразу очистить её вызовом free или передать одним указателем в функцию.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>


void print_name(const char* array[3][4], size_t num) {
    printf("%s\n", array[num][0]);
}


int main(void) {
    const char* names[3][4];

    names[0][0] = "kola";
    names[1][0] = "vasa";
    names[2][0] = "misa";

    print_name(names, 2);
}
```

Comment: мне нельзя изменять типы переменных и параметров:(